How can I get array from json in unity？
I get a json str in unity:
{"action":"result","code":"0","data":"{\"seg_id\":2,\"cn\":{\"st\":{\"rt\":[{\"ws\":[{\"cw\":[{\"sc\":0.00,\"w\":\"今天\",\"wp\":\"n\",\"rl\":\"0\",\"wb\":9,\"wc\":0.00,\"we\":52}],\"wb\":9,\"we\":52},{\"cw\":[{\"sc\":0.00,\"w\":\"天气\",\"wp\":\"n\",\"rl\":\"0\",\"wb\":53,\"wc\":0.00,\"we\":92}],\"wb\":53,\"we\":92},{\"cw\":[{\"sc\":0.00,\"w\":\"怎么样\",\"wp\":\"n\",\"rl\":\"0\",\"wb\":93,\"wc\":0.00,\"we\":156}],\"wb\":93,\"we\":156},{\"cw\":[{\"sc\":0.00,\"w\":\"？\",\"wp\":\"p\",\"rl\":\"0\",\"wb\":156,\"wc\":0.00,\"we\":156}],\"wb\":156,\"we\":156}]}],\"bg\":\"160\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ed\":\"1900\"}},\"ls\":true}","desc":"success","sid":"rta02434f94@dx5bb219816a261aba00"}

And I create classes ,using JsonUtility.fromJson to parse it.
public class JsonData
{
    public string action;

    public string code;

    public Data data;

    public string desc;

    public string sid;
}

[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public string seg_id;
    [Serializable]
    public class CN
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class ST
        {
            [Serializable]
            public class RT
            {
                [Serializable]
                public class WS
                {
                    [Serializable]
                    public class CW
                    {
                        public string w;
                        public string wp;
                    }

                    public CW[] cw;
                    public string wb;
                    public string we;
                }

                public WS[] ws;
            }
            public RT rt;
            public string bg;
            public string type;
            public string ed;
        }

        public ST st;
    }
    public CN cn;
    public string ls;
}

but the result turns out empty.
I use JsonUtility.toJson ,it cant get any value in data.
However,I want to get the value w in json, how can I get it?
I've tested other methods, but still can parse it.

Im not sure what the second class is, but how are you telling it to convert your json?

Can you confirm your JSON format? Currently data is a nested and escaped JSON strings within your given JSON so the actual valid c# data structure would currently just look like public class Root { public string action; public string code; public string data; public string desc; public string sid; } ....

I see the Json was not formatting and I did a fix. I generated the C# file with the Json and found that I can able to get the array values in it. I used Newtonsoft assembly to deserialize the Json to class. After I made the changes I can see the value populated in the w property as below

Please find the class files used to deserialize the Json to C# class.
public class Cn
{
    public St st { get; set; }
}

public class Cw
{
    public double sc { get; set; }
    public string w { get; set; }
    public string wp { get; set; }
    public string rl { get; set; }
    public int wb { get; set; }
    public double wc { get; set; }
    public int we { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int seg_id { get; set; }
    public Cn cn { get; set; }
    public bool ls { get; set; }
}

public class JsonData
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public string sid { get; set; }
}

public class Rt
{
    public List<W> ws { get; set; }
}

public class St
{
    public List<Rt> rt { get; set; }
    public string bg { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string ed { get; set; }
}

public class W
{
    public List<Cw> cw { get; set; }
    public int wb { get; set; }
    public int we { get; set; }
}

Please find the code to deserialze the Json to C# class file
string sampleJson = @"{
  ""action"":""result"",
  ""code"":""0"",
  ""data"":{
    ""seg_id"":2,
    ""cn"":
    {
        ""st"": {
          ""rt"":[
            {""ws"":
              [
                {""cw"":
                  [
                    {
                      ""sc"":0.00,
                      ""w"":""今天"",
                      ""wp"":""n"",
                      ""rl"":""0"",
                      ""wb"":9,
                      ""wc"":0.00,
                      ""we"":52}
                  ],
                ""wb"":9,
                ""we"":52
              },
              {
                ""cw"":[{
                    ""sc"":0.00,
                    ""w"":""天气"",
                    ""wp"":""n"",
                    ""rl"":""0"",
                    ""wb"":53,
                    ""wc"":0.00,
                    ""we"":92
                  }],
                  ""wb"":53,
                  ""we"":92
              },
              {
                ""cw"":[{
                  ""sc"":0.00,
                  ""w"":""怎么样"",
                  ""wp"":""n"",
                  ""rl"":""0"",
                  ""wb"":93,
                  ""wc"":0.00,
                  ""we"":156
                }],
                ""wb"":93,
                ""we"":156
              },
              {
                ""cw"":[{
                  ""sc"":0.00,
                  ""w"":""？"",
                  ""wp"":""p"",
                  ""rl"":""0"",
                  ""wb"":156,
                  ""wc"":0.00,
                  ""we"":156
                }],
                ""wb"":156,
                ""we"":156
              }]
            }]
            ,""bg"":""160"",
            ""type"":""0"",
            ""ed"":""1900""
        }
      },
    ""ls"":true
  },
  ""desc"":""success"",
  ""sid"":""rta02434f94@dx5bb219816a261aba00""
}";

JsonData myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(sampleJson);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
Console.ReadKey();

